# How to append a data to an object property in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to send request to a mongodb database.
For example I have this object:

```
{
  id:"1",
  requestType : {
     "api1" : {count:12,firstTime:12},
     "api2" : {count:6,firstTime:18}
   }
}
```

after getting data by "id" I want to append another row to "requestType" for example "api3":{count:56,firstTime:11}.
my expected object is:

```
{
   id:"1",
   requestType : {
       "api1" : {count:12,firstTime:12},
       "api2" : {count:6,firstTime:18},
       "api3":{count:56,firstTime:11}
    }
 }
```

currently I'm using this query by mongoose:

```
apiAttemptsModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, {
    $set: {
        requestType : {"api3":{count:56,firstTime:11}}
    }
}, {upsert: true, new: true}, function (err, row) {
    if (err) {
        callback('err is ' + err)
    } else {
        callback(row);
    }
});
```

But this code will exchange old requestType object with the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
apiAttemptsModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, {
    $set: {
        "requestType.api3" : {count:56, firstTime:11}
    }
}, {upsert: true, new: true}, function (err, row) {
    if (err) {
        callback('err is ' + err)
    } else {
        callback(row);
    }
});
```

By the way, this is not the proper way to use callbacks.
callbacks in node are usually called with the following signature:
`function(error, data)` -
thus when calling `callback(row);` a user of this method might expect an error there, much like you did with the callback function on line 5.
The first argument is usually `null` when no error has occurred.

In addition, calling `callback('err is ' + err)` will only keep the error's message and discard its stack trace, because the error is "converted" to a string.

I'd convert your code to:

```
apiAttemptsModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, {
    $set: {
        "requestType.api3" : {count:56, firstTime:11}
    }
}, {upsert: true, new: true}, function (err, row) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err)
    } else {
        callback(null, row);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set upset to false.  This will update the document, but will not create it if it does not already exist.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/